# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle, exception

Having this error whenever running a project in Visual Studio Code.

[image: Error]

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

here's very lightweight solution with steps:

- Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S or File->Project Structure
- Select Project from left panel
- Now check your Gradle Version at right panel
- In my case my Gradle Version is 3.3
- Navigate C:\Users\ashish.gradle\caches and delete your Gradle
  Version - 3.3 named folder.
- Now restart or open your project again from workspace.

Comment: Didn't work for me.